# i want to retrieve data from table where column are same

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table named product with following data:

```
maker model type
A   1232    PC
A   1233    PC
A   1276    Printer
A   1298    Laptop
A   1401    Printer
A   1408    Printer
A   1752    Laptop
B   1121    PC
B   1750    Laptop
C   1321    Laptop
D   1288    Printer
D   1433    Printer
E   1260    PC
E   1434    Printer
E   2112    PC
E   2113    PC
```

i want to retrieve maker and type

condition 1: who produce only the models of the same type.
condition 2: the number of those models exceeds 1.

result desired:

```
maker   type
D       Printer
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the maker:

```
select distinct maker
from your_table
group by maker
having count(distinct type) = 1
and count(*) > 1
```

To get maker and type:

```
select distinct t.maker, t.type
from your_table t
inner join
(
   select maker
   from your_table
   group by maker
   having count(distinct type) = 1
   and count(*) > 1
) x on x.maker = t.maker
```

Comment: Use `select distinct`

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select 
    distinct Maker, Type 
from(
    select 
        *, 
        COUNT(*) over (partition by Maker, type) TypeCnt,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by Maker) MakerCnt
    from YourTable
)x where TypeCnt=MakerCnt and TypeCnt>1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT types.[maker],  types.[type] FROM
(SELECT [maker],   COUNT([model]) as cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [maker]) makers
INNER JOIN
(SELECT [maker],  [type], COUNT([model]) as cnt
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [maker],  [type]) types
ON makers.[maker] = types.[maker]
AND makers.cnt = types.cnt
AND types.cnt > 1
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/623a60/5)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT maker, MIN(type) AS type
FROM product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING MIN(type) = MAX(type)
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT model) > 1 ;
```